# Using Javascript to add a span around a decimal value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var value = 2.00
```

How can I add a span tag around the '.00', so that on my page I would end up with:

```
2<span>.00</span>
```

Please note that the '00' can be a different value. Depends on the data being injected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)**

```js
var value = '2.00';
console.log(
  value.replace(/\.(\d+)/, '.<sapn>$1</span>')
);
```

---

If variable holds a `Number` then convert it to 2 decimal format string using **[`Number#toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)** and do the same.

```js
var value = 2.00;
console.log(
  value.toFixed(2).replace(/\.(\d+)/, '.<sapn>$1</span>')
);
```

---

Refer : [Specifying a string as a parameter in replace method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).

Comment: what is $1?? I need to be able to inject the decimal value '.00' into the span tag

Comment: @Richy : $1 is captured value .... in this case `(\d+)` , the digit after `.` ... Refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter

Comment: return needs to be in HTML

Comment: Sorry my bad. I am using HTML.. Need to add some additional code. Great job. thanks

Answer (score 1):

split it into the two parts and add a span to the second part.not sure if you want the decimal place inside the span or not, but this will do it.

```js
var value = '2.00';
var valueParts=value.split(".");
var newValue=valueParts[0] +"<span>."+valueParts[1]+ "</span>";
alert(newValue);
```

Comment: return value needs to be in HTML

Answer (score 0):

Use the [toFixed](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) function

```
var num = 5.56789;
var n = num.toFixed(2);
```

if you need back the string to number you can use [parseFloat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) function

```
var num = parseFloat(n)
```

Comment: note that n is now a string and will need to be arsed back into a number if calculkcations are required on it

Comment: normally you must divide presentation from model. keep your current float value intact and convert a formatted copy

Comment: apologies, you werent able to see the span tag around the decimal value.

Comment: this does not add a span to the decimal place portion as requested in the OP

Comment: to add span you can use the [Pranav](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37970590/816721) replace function

Answer (score 0):

You are specifically asking for a "span tag", so here is a JQuery approach:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var value = 2.00
  value = value.toFixed(2);

  $('body').append(value.split('.')[0] + '<span>.' + value.split('.')[1] + '</span>');
});
```

See this jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/fictus/tj7df8qh/